# session between web api and angular 2

Tags: angular, session, asp.net-web-api

i want to save data on session in web api by calling it from angular 2 application.

i use this line to save in the session in the first request(with no body) from the angular:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["userID"]="test";
```

and in this line to read from the session in the second request from the angular:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["userID"]
```

but the value of "userID" is null.

any idea?

note that in post man request its work fine. see like the problem its because the request is from angular.
thanks!

Comment: You have to enable sessions (otherwise every session will be considered new). That being said, don't store state data in the session if you can avoid it (most times you can).  It will impact the ability for your service to scale.

Comment: How to enable sessions?